# Expanding Nav Items on Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I am having an issue with an expanding side-navigation.

In the Fiddle below, you can see what the side-navigation looks like when on the Bachelor's of Science in Physics page. This page is a child element of the Undergraduate, Programs and Degrees, and Science items, and is marked with a class of "current-page".

The problem, though, is that if a keyboard-only user is tabbing through the side-navigation and goes to the Arts section above, or a section under the "Graduate" list below, these elements will not expand to show which link they currently have tabbed to. For example:

- If I tab to the Arts section, and then tab to Graphic Design, I can't see what I have selected because "Arts" is still closed.
- If I tab to "Bachelor's Degree in Biology (BS or BA)" and then tab to the "Pre-Medicine Concentration", I can't see what I have selected because that "Bachelor's" list item is still closed.
- If I continue tabbing to the Graduate section, I can't see which sub-item I have tabbed to there either.

How would I code this so that these sections will expand if a child element has been tabbed to?

Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/eLsb50f3/

```
    /* Expanding Side Navigation  */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').addClass('js');
  var $menu = $('#expanding-side-nav'),
    $toplink = $('#expanding-side-nav-top-link'),
    $menulink = $('.expanding-side-menu-link'),
    $menuTrigger = $('.has-subnav > a > .side-more-link');

  $menulink.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $menulink.toggleClass('active');

  });

  $menuTrigger.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('active').parent().next('ul').toggleClass('active');

  });


  $menulink.click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $menu.offset().top
    }, 500);
  });

  $toplink.click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('body').offset().top
    }, 500);
  });

  /* setting the default states. */
  // first set an active class on all ULs that are the parent of the current page.
  $('.expanding-side-menu .current-page').parents('nav ul').addClass('active');
  // then expand the .side-more-link of all currently expanded ULs in the nav.
  $('.expanding-side-menu .current-page').parents('nav ul.active').prev().find('.side-more-link').addClass('active');
  // then make the chidren of the current node visible.
  $('.expanding-side-menu .current-page ~ ul').addClass('active');
  // and make the current node + sign a minus
  $('.expanding-side-menu .current-page .side-more-link').addClass('active');
});

//If user has tabbed to an LI that is under a UL that is not active,
//then we need to open the parent UL so that the user can see what
//they have tabbed to...
```

Comment: Use `.focus` instead of `.click`

Comment: The code above is the existing base-code for the sidenav - It wouldn't let me pose the link to JSFiddle without any code for some reason.

Right now, there's just the comments at the end for what I'm trying to do...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pure css by using the `:focus-within` pseudo-class.
See the example below. Admittedly it's simple just to demonstrate the method.
Select "Top Level Page A" and you can then use tab and shift-tab to navigate.

```css
.menu ul {
  display: none;
}

.menu:focus-within ul {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="menu_link" tabindex="0">Top Level Page A</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#" class="menu_link" tabindex="0">Sub Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu_link" tabindex="0">Sub Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu_link" tabindex="0">Sub Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="menu_link" tabindex="0">Top Level Page B</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#" class="menu_link" tabindex="0">Sub Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu_link" tabindex="0">Sub Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu_link" tabindex="0">Sub Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="menu_link" tabindex="0">Top Level Page C</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#" class="menu_link" tabindex="0">Sub Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu_link" tabindex="0">Sub Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu_link" tabindex="0">Sub Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```